# Modelling EVERY day in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a booking system for something where the price can change based on the day. The admins for the site can make these changes. If a booking crosses the boundary of a daily rate, they pay pro-rata for the rates they used.

I'm losing confidence in how this is implemented. There are at least two ways:

- Having Rates that specify their validity (start, end fields) and then working out which of those apply. But which overlapping ones take priority? Etc. Nasty. This is what we're trying to do and cannot currently answer sufficiently well.
- The same except that there is some form of unique quality to date so that no two rates can overlap. The problem here is we'd need to split existing Rates on insert and rejoin two on delete/edit, etc if they had the same value. We'd need to make sure there were no gaps. It requires some heavy ORM overriding.
- Keeping a DayRate table with *every* day defined. This means keeping a load of extra data around but most bookings are for tens of days, not thousands so I'm not worried about the database bandwidth requirements here. Date would be primary-unique and I'd just do a range filter for grabbing which ones I need to factor in.

  The problem is generating these dates ahead of time. I *know* that as soon as I implement this, somebody will make a booking for 2032. Is there a good way around this or *should* we limit them?

None of these answers seems great and I have to imagine that I'm not the first guy with a booking system. Is there a better way of keeping track of a rate over a contiguous (possibly infinite) amount of time?

Comment: Would a [`DateRangeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#daterangefield) not work?.. you just make sure you always have a start/end (epoch and now+20yrs maybe if needed?) I'm not sure if I fully understood the question though

Comment: @Sayse Yeah the first two solutions use that. It's what we're currently trying to use. The problem (that the first two discuss) is overriding. You either allow overlaps and figure out a priority, or you split ranges up when you want to override and things get super-complicates.

Comment: Well I'd imagine the priority would be easy to work out though, its the one that takes the bigger chunk of the customers mon- uh.. Is most beneficial to the customer/company (something which you're product manager would need to decide)

Comment: The problem is the complexity that comes when we try to get the pro-rata total. I need the rate for each day in the booking range. With a date-centric model (the third option above), I just tick through the values in the range. With ranges and overlaps I have to work this all out manually.

Comment: I think thats just a price you might have to pay, it certainly sounds like less work than having a separate table hanging around (perhaps). From my (limited?) experience with booking systems I've always understood it that the fee I pay is based upon the starting dates fee, but I understand you seem to be looking to be more flexible, which is why I suggested it might be better to figure out what your product owner would expect (if you haven't already). I'm not sure how much more help I could be I'm afraid, I'll delete my comments if you wish or feel they detract from your question

Comment: They're useful. They're making me explain my logic. Yeah the reason for pro-rata-ing is there are "surge" periods like holidays. It seems petty to charge every day at the higher rate because it overlapped by one day (for example).

Comment: Sure, if it helps at all, it would seem that Premier inn might use a day rate table [(see price breakdown)](http://www.premierinn.com/gb/en/hotels/england/greater-manchester/manchester/manchester-city-centre-deansgate-locks.html?INNID=MANPTI&ARRdd=18&ARRmm=04&ARRyyyy=2016&NIGHTS=7&ROOMS=1&ADULT1=1&CHILD1=0&COT1=0&INTTYP1=DB&SID=4&ISH=true&BRAND=PI), I could only guess at how this would be implemented though.